# Tensorflow tensordot for unknown batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, matrix-multiplication

there might be an obvious solution, but I haven't found it yet. I want to do a simple multiplication, where I have one tensor that gives me a kind of weight vector and another one that are stacked tensors (same number as weights). It seems straight forward using `tf.tensordot` but that doesn't work for unknown batch sizes.

```
import collections
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='y_true')

# These are the models that I want to combine
linear_model0 = tf.layers.Dense(units=1, name='linear_model0')
linear_model1 = tf.layers.Dense(units=1, name='linear_model1')
agents = collections.OrderedDict()
agents[0] = linear_model0(x)  # shape (?,4,1)
agents[1] = linear_model1(x)  # shape (?,4,1)
stacked = tf.stack(list(agents.values()), axis=1)  # shape (?,2,4,1)

# This is the model that produces the weights
x_flat = tf.layers.Flatten()(x)
weight_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=2, name='weight_model')
weights = weight_model(x_flat)  # shape: (?,2)

# This is the final output
y_pred = tf.tensordot(weights, stacked, axes = 2, name='y_pred')
# PROBLEM HERE: shape: (4,1) instead of (?,4,1) 

# Running the whole thing
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

# Example1 (output of shape (1,4,1) expected, got (4,1))
print('model', sess.run(y_pred,
                        {x: [[[1], [2], [3], [4]]]}).shape)

# Example2 (output of (2,4,1) expected, got (4,1))
print('model', sess.run(y_pred,
                        {x: [[[1], [2], [3], [4]], [[1], [2], [3], [4]]]}).shape)
```

So, the multiplication works as expected for the first input, but does only that first one and not a batch of inputs. Any help?

Similar questions that didn't resolve my issue:

- [obstacles in tensorflow's tensordot using batch multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108505/obstacles-in-tensorflows-tensordot-using-batch-multiplication)

Comment: Did you try tf.einsum? ```tf.einsum('ij,ijkl->ikl', weights, stacked)```

Comment: @Amir I did try it but not like that! This works! Thank you! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?! :)

Comment: Happy to see that it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) is not suitable in the case because, based on your explanation, it necessary to set axis equal to 1 which cause the incompatibility in matrix sizes. One is `[batch_size, 2]` the other is `[batch_size, 8]`. On the other, If you set the axis to `[[1],[1]]` it is not what you expected:

```
tf.tensordot(weights, stacks, axes=[[1],[1]]) # shape = (?,?,1,1)
```

*How to fix the issue?*

Use [`tf.ensim`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) as contraction between tensors of arbitrary dimension:

```
tf.einsum('ij,ijkl->ikl', weights, stacked)
```